# Remove irrelevant menu from Marlin 2.0

Tags: marlin

I'm using a Velleman K8400 with a Velleman LED strips. The strips aren't able to adjust luminosity only color, so the Custom Lights menu item is irrelevant to my printer. How do I remove the menu item? I can see how to easily add menus and items, but not much reference as to how to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your hardware configuration and the firmware setup of your Configuration.h, the LED menu will be made available through the [menu_led.cpp](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/menu/menu_led.cpp) sources. Apparently, this work for you already considering you see too many entries.

To disable entries, you need to disable these in the afore mentioned code file.

To find where this menu is added to the configuration of the LCD menu structure you could search (*the GitHub.com website provides a powerful search tool to search within the sources of projects*) for the "Custom Lights" menu caption in the Marlin sources to find this caption is used by constant `MSG_CUSTOM_LEDS`, see the language translation file [language_en.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/language/language_en.h)

```
LSTR MSG_CUSTOM_LEDS                    = _UxGT("Custom Lights");
```

Now searching for the `MSG_CUSTOM_LEDS` constant will lead you to the file [menu_led.cpp](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/menu/menu_led.cpp); more specific, [this line](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/menu/menu_led.cpp#L154):

```
SUBMENU(MSG_CUSTOM_LEDS, menu_led_custom);
```

If you disable this line, recompile the firmware and upload it to your controller board you would see that the submenu has disappeared.